# Trying to register script in footer

Tags: functions, user-registration, wp-register-script

My problem is the script is not registering in the footer it, is just disappearing, although the `jquery.js` does show up in the head.

I have the following code in my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()
{

    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fittext.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

This is what my template page looks like:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:Tech Basics
*/
?>
<?php get_header( 'tech' ); ?>

<div id="quote">
    <h1 id="fittext3">Sending you the techie! son you never had.</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#fittext3").fitText(1.1, { minFontSize: 50, maxFontSize: '75px' });
    </script>
<div class="row mainContent">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <?php 
        $page_id = 10; // 123 should be replaced with a specific Page's id from your site, which you can find by mousing over the link to edit that Page on the Manage Pages admin page. The id will be         embedded in the query string of the URL, e.g. page.php?action=edit&post=123.

        $page_data = get_page( $page_id ); // You must pass in a variable to the get_page function. If you pass in a value (e.g. get_page ( 123 ); ), WordPress will generate an error. By default, this will return an object.

        echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); // echo the content and retain Wordpress filters such as paragraph tags. Origin from: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_pagepost-and-no-paragraphs-problem
?>
    </div>
</div><!--row ends-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

`footer.php`:

```
        </div>
        <!--mainColumns ends-->
    </div>
    <!--main div ends-->
</div>
<!--container ends-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`wp_footer()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_footer/) call in your footer, before closing `body` tag. Theme without it is pretty much considered broken, since things like footer scripts simply can't work without it.

Comment: ok I added <?php wp_footer(); ?>  and it worked thanks!